# Resolving dependencies taking more than 2hrs

Tags: flutter-dependencies

I'm using vs code, flutter, i just started using it but when i created a first project it's taking forever to resolve the dependencies, it took more than 2hours and still not resolved. My internet works first with other sites.

I tried waiting but nothing. I have the latest flutter and dart.